# How to keep the scroll bar "exactly in the bottom with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a small snippet of a simple chat style program.

```
<html>
    <script src="http://libs.baidu.com/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("button").on("click", function(){
                $('.inner').scrollTop($('.container')[0].scrollHeight);
                var a = new Date();
                $(".container").append("<p>"+a+"</p>");
                if($(".container").height()>$(".inner").height()){
                    $(".container").css("bottom", "auto");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>


    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper{
            width:300px;
            height: 500px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .inner{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            background-color: #ccc;
            position: relative;
        }

        .container{
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
    <body>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <p>Hey buddy!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button>Try Me!</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

The program is working now, but the scroll bar is not scrolled to the bottom. What have I done wrong? Please help me on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3g2ygmd/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to scroll after you added the new html :

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9a6xrrss/)

```
$(function(){
    $("button").on("click", function(){

        var a = new Date();
        $(".container").append("<p>"+a+"</p>");
        if($(".container").height()>$(".inner").height()){
            $(".container").css("bottom", "auto");
        }
        $('.inner').scrollTop($('.container')[0].scrollHeight);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this,

```
 $("button").on("click", function(){
     $(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

nafischonchol, thank you so much for this answer, amazing I used it like this, and it keeps the scrollbar at the bottom all the time.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var intervalId = window.setInterval(function(){
   $(document).scrollTop($(document).height());    
  }, 200);
});
```